# loading data asynchronously with multipe Axios calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-effect

I have a bunch of charts to display and need to load data separately for each of them.

The data structure identifying each chart is array and looks like this (subarray can host one or more charts. In case of multiple items in subarray, the chart will have multiple axis):

```
"charts":[["chart1"], ["chart2", "chart4", ...], ...]
```

There is not known in advance how many items will be in the array and how much they will have subitems.

**My approach**

First I go through `charts` and display placeholders (loaders), then if `data` state is available, display the chart:

```
const[data, setData] = useState(null);

return(
  charts.map(item => {
     (item in data && data[item] !== "") ? <Chart data={data[item]} /> : <Loader />
  })
)
```

For the `Axios` data fetch I thought to use `useEffect` which would fill the `data` state variable, which would then re-render the component to show already loaded charts.

My issue here is, that I am not sure how to utilise `useEffect` to do this as calling `Axios` in a loop and setting `data` state variable in a loop does not seem right to me. I guess it would then create infinite loop.

The other a bit smaller question is, how to wait for data load of all subitems to display multiaxis chart, if it applies.

Comment: May be consider using Promise.all and you may be able to do `setData` on the callback. Another alternative may be `async` - `await`.

Comment: @jsN00b sure. If I want to wait for all data to load and then apply all of them on charts at once. But if I want to render each chart when its data are ready, then I guess this is not the way?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your actual problem is. It sounds like you are making multiple axios calls spread out because the data size is too large to make over one request?  If so why are you not just updating setData as each response comes in?

Comment: @coot3 I communicate with the REST and the request's structure is unchangeable. Also the data for each chart are from different data groups. That is why multiple requests. I want to display each chart as soon as its data are ready. Not sure how to do that requests and responses in useEffect, or if there is another way

Answer (score 0):

Based off the comments, here is an example of updating setData in a useEffect hook with the responses from multiple api calls to different endpoints:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async(url) => {
    const res = await axios.get(url)
    setData(prevState => [...prevState, res.data])
  }
  getData(url1)
  getData(url2)
  getData(url3)
}, [])
```

Comment: thank you, but three questions here. Will the setData wait with re-rendering component until all 3 requests are done inside useEffect? Would not be better to setData after all requests are done? And regarding getData, as per question, it is not known how many requests there will be, so can't call it like that.